# Python - using a variable to determine which array is to be used?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, user-interface

I am trying to put together a python program for an I.T project I am doing at school and it is doing my head in! I am very new to python so I'm really struggling here.

Anyway, the program I am creating is supposed to convert numbers into words (in english and maori). For example, if the user clicks on "1" the image on the screen changes to "one" when english is selected and "tahi" when maori is selected. I have two lists, one for each language (I'm only using numbers 1-10), and I need to change which list is being passed through my number_converter function when the user clicks on a language in a drop-down list.

I have been trying to do this by using a variable in the number_converter function that is replaced by either of the two lists' names. Sorry if this is all very confusing, I'm having a hard time understanding it myself! Anyway, here's my code, maybe you can figure it out:

```
# Number Converter Version 1.04

import tkinter, sys

class newpulldownlist:
# Creates a pull-down list of options through mypulldown = newpulldownlist(parent,     [array of options], command)
# mypulldown.value() returns the selected item
# mypulldown.chngevlue("to this") forces a selection change
# mypulldown.options (without brackets) returns an array of the option choices
# By default, fist item in the list is pre-selected.
def __init__ (self, parent, valuearray, cmd):

    self.options = valuearray

    self.listvariable = tkinter.StringVar()
    self.listvariable.set(valuearray[0])
    self.guilist = tkinter.OptionMenu(parent, self.listvariable, *valuearray, command = cmd)
    self.guilist.configure(width = "0")
    self.guilist.pack()

def value(self):
    return self.listvariable.get()

def changevalue(self, tothis):
    self.listvariable.set(tothis)

class newbutton:
# Create a new button as mybutton = newbutton(parent, x, y, startingtext, command)
def __init__ (self, parent, x, y, label, cmd):
    self.width = x
    self.height = y
    self.label = label

    self.guibut = tkinter.Button(parent, width = x, height = y, text = label, command = cmd)
    self.guibut.pack(side = "left")

def number_select(n):                       # Image changing function, calls images from the 'number' array.
global language
print("You pressed", n, ".")            # One function is used to streamline the code and avoid having a function for each number.
picture.delete('all')
newpic = picture.create_image(602, 2, image = language[n], anchor = "n")

def select(self):
options = lang_list.value()
print(lang_list.value())

# Window.

appwindow = tkinter.Tk()    # Makes window
appwindow.title("Number Converter")

rightside = tkinter.Frame(appwindow)
rightside.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT)

topside = tkinter.Frame(appwindow)
topside.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)

bottomside = tkinter.Frame(appwindow)
bottomside.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)

picture = tkinter.Canvas(topside, width = 1200, height = 70, bg = "white")
picture.pack()

# Arrays for each language.

options = ['English', 'Maori']

maori = []
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "Title_1.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "1_Tahi.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "2_Rua.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "3_Toru.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "4_Wha.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "5_Rima.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "6_Ono.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "7_Whitu.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "8_Waru.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "9_Iwa.gif"))
maori.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "10_Tekau.gif"))

english = []
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "Title_1.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "1.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "2.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "3.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "4.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "5.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "6.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "7.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "8.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "9.gif"))
english.append(tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "10.gif"))

lang_list = newpulldownlist(appwindow, options, cmd = select)

language = lang_list.value()

if options == 'Maori':
language = maori
print("Maori")

elif options == 'English':
language = english
print("English")

startpic = picture.create_image(602, 2, image = language[0], anchor = "n")

# Buttons

one = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "1", cmd = lambda n=1: number_select(n))
two = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "2", cmd = lambda n=2: number_select(n))
three = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "3", cmd = lambda n=3: number_select(n))
four = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "4", cmd = lambda n=4: number_select(n))
five = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "5", cmd = lambda n=5: number_select(n))
six = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "6", cmd = lambda n=6: number_select(n))
seven = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "7", cmd = lambda n=7: number_select(n))
eight = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "8", cmd = lambda n=8: number_select(n))
nine = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "9", cmd = lambda n=9: number_select(n))
ten = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "10", cmd = lambda n=10: number_select(n))

quitbutton = newbutton(bottomside, 12, 1, "Quit", cmd = sys.exit)

# Number converter debug

print("    Number Converter Debug    ")
print("##############################")

appwindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it right, I think my approach would be to use a dictionary.  You would do something like `numbers = {'maori': maori, 'english': english}`, and then calling `language = numbers['maori']` returns the list `maori`.  So your language drop-down could just change a string variable between `'english'` and `'maori'`, which you pass to the dictionary to select the appropriate language.

Edit: More on dictionaries [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).